# Angular 2 convert string to md5 hash

Tags: javascript, angular, md5

I found the [ts-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-md5) package but in the example it has a `hashStr` method but now it doesn't.

> Property 'hashStr' does not exist on type `Md5`.

That error is logged in my console after using that. How can I do that?

I tried inject it in constructor

```
constructor(private _md5: Md5) {}
```

and then

```
let a: any = this._md5.hashStr("password");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just checked out the documentation and source code, and the `hashStr` method doesn't exist on instances of the `Md5` class.

This means that if you only need to use the `hashStr` method, you don't need to initialize the class in your constructor since you can just call the method directly on the `Md5` class:

```
let hash = Md5.hashStr("password");
```

If you want to generate the hash from an instance (rather than the class), then you would use the `appendStr` method and then chain the `end()` method:

```
let hash = _md5.appendStr('password').end();
```

Also, since you're using Angular 2, remember to add the `Md5` class in your component's `providers` array if you are initializing it in your constructor:

```
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [Md5]
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(
    private _md5: Md5
  ) {
    let hash = Md5.hashStr("password");

    // or ...

    let hash2 = _md5.appendStr('password').end();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using this same code in my NativeScript + Angular app, I am getting output as, **[mcd's iPhone]: EncryptedPwd is. NaN**

Comment: NaN , output I am getting.Do u having any idea to solve this?