# Generate unique id when saving JSON to Ionic / Cordova storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

If it helps this is an example of an object:

```
export class Foo {
    public id: number; // <- good practice when setting this?
    public bar: string;
}
```

I'm making a simple app using Ionic that stores some JSON objects to local storage - so no service that helps with giving an unique identity to that object.

Objects have an Id field that is used to uniquely identify and find them in a list of objects of same class.

Do Ionic/Angular/Cordova provide any help with generating unique ID-s? Or do I have to iterate over all objects to find an unique Id every time I create a new object?

Comment: how about `counter++`?

Comment: @JBNizet so have a `counter` that is set to the largest id of all stored objects at application start? Sure, seems like a good approach. Hoping for a something that could handle that for me tho?

Comment: It would be faster to implement that solution than to write the question.

Comment: @JBNizet :D see what you mean. I'm just checking if I'm reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **new Date()** and **md5**.

Check this: [how to generate md5 hash in angular 2 typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299630/how-to-generate-md5-hash-in-angular-2-typescript) and 
[Angular 2 convert string to md5 hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179618/angular-2-convert-string-to-md5-hash)

```
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [Md5]
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(
    private _md5: Md5
  ) {
    let time = new Date();
    let hash = Md5.hashStr(time);//unique id
  }
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Cool! So no ionic/angular support for this?

Comment: Is there any drawback to just using `new Date().valueOf()` as the Id? Like using current time in milliseconds as a unique Id?